# ?: (staticfiles.E002) Error The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting . how to solve this error?

Tags: python-3.x

```
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
```

if you recieved this error, on internet you will find lots of solution. As none them worked for me I am writing down what worked for me. I only have 1 static files folder

Comment: Please consider adding more details like version, env, when how you are getting this error and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1: Simplest way is when using command collectstatic.py , comment out STATICFILES_DIRS... It looks like:

```
#STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"/static/")
```

And after that comment out STATIC_ROOT, so that it looks like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
#STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"/static/")
```

Solution 2:
change STATIC_ROOT to e.g.

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/projects/site/assets/'
```

and in urls.py add line:

```
urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL,       document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Any one of the solutions should work for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"/static/")
```

and url settings should be

```
urlpatterns = [
some__ulrs
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```